# Can I get rid of nested for loops here?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a function that takes a vector and returns a vector by combining all the elements in it. Right now, I have 3 nested for loops that create a combination that is 3 levels deep. I would like it to look better and have the ability to add the functionality to make it 4 levels deep when I want.

If input = ["one", "two", "three"]

3 level output = "onetwothree" "twoonethree" and so on.

```
std::vector<std::string> generator(std::vector<std::string>& x)
{
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::string tmp;
    for (auto i : x) {
        output.push_back(i);
        for (auto j : x) {
            tmp = i + j;
            output.push_back(tmp);
            for (auto k : x) {
                tmp = i + j + k;
                output.push_back(tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

I have looked into iterators, but I can't figure out if it would work.

Comment: _"I have looked into iterators, but I can't figure out if it would work."_ The range based for loops you're using are already iterator based, I seriously doubt these would improve anything. Probably that code could be written better using [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation).

Comment: This looks close to another [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  Forget about mentioning dictionary attacks or anything else not relevant.  You have a vector of 3 items -- are you trying to create a vector that has the permutations of those 3 items?

Comment: *I have 3 nested for loops that create a combination that is 3 levels deep.* -- There is no need for triple nested  loops if you had use proper data structure and algorithm.  Something like `std::next_permutation`.

Comment: Looks like something that's trivially done using recursion. The real trick here would be doing this efficiently.

Comment: If what you are looking for is to simply generate the permutation of all the elements of the string vector `x` and store this permutation into the output, this is easily accomplished by using `std::next_permutation` and `std::accumulate`.  Before posting an answer, Is it  something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c29eb2c55c41152) what you're looking for?

Comment: ... actually, what was I thinking... Don't need recursion here. The whole thing can be replaced by a single for loop, and some basic math.

Comment: According to the solution he posted, I think he would like combinations with repetitions (and different sizes too apparently). Like: one, oneone, oneoneone, onetwo, onetwo...etc

Comment: @ihavenoidea -- But given the description, his solution is seemingly trying to fumble its way into creating simple permutation of string elements.  I wouldn't read too much into the actual code, but concentrate on the requirements the OP posted.

Comment: Yeah, at least for me his expected output examples are not clear given his proposed solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If what you are looking for is to simply generate the permutations of all the elements of the string vector `x` and store these permutations into another output vector, this is easily accomplished by using [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> generator(std::vector<std::string> x)
{
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::sort(x.begin(), x.end());
    do 
    {
        output.push_back(std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.end(), std::string()));
    } while (std::next_permutation(x.begin(), x.end()));
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    auto v = generator({"one","two","three"});
    for (auto& val : v)
        std::cout << val << "\n";
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c29eb2c55c41152)

The `std::accumulate` basically calls `operator +` on the elements by default, thus the string is automatically concatenated.

As far as `std::next_permutation`, the description of what it does is explained at the link.  Basically you want to start out with a sorted sequence, and call `std::next_permutation` to get the next permutation of elements.

Note that this is not contingent of the number of "levels" (as you call it).  You could have a vector of 10 strings, and this would work correctly (assuming there are no memory constraints).

Comment: The OP generates `111` but yours does not.

Comment: OP also generates `1` and `11`

Comment: he needed combinations not permutations.

Comment: I enclosed the section described here, in a for-loop to create 1, 11, 111 and so on.
`for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
  do 
  {
   output.push_back(std::accumulate(x.begin(),
   x.end() - i, std::string()));
  } while (std::next_permutation(x.begin(), x.end()));
 }`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate all combinations of N words with max length L you could use this:

```
std::vector<std::string> generator(const std::vector<std::string> & x, int levels) {
    int nWords = x.size();

    std::vector<std::string> output;
    for (int l = 1; l <= levels; ++l) {
        int nCombs = std::pow(nWords, l); 
        for (int i = 0; i < nCombs; ++i) {
            std::string cur;
            for (int j = 0, k = i; j < l; ++j) {
                cur += x[k%nWords];
                k /= nWords;
            }
            output.push_back(cur);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2848424fe79ad2b5)

There are still 3 nested loops, but this works for any value of L - not just 3. L > N also works.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the similar problem in Python once.

The goal I suppose is to have a "`n`-nested" loops such that `n` is a variable. A better result would be to make each index `I_i` of level `i` be variables. That is to say, given a list `[I_1,I_2,...,I_n]`, you should be able to generate such loop

```
for i_1 in range( I_1):
    for i_2 in range( I_2):
       ...
          for i_n in range(I_n):
             some_function(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)
```

One way to do this is to use mathematics. You can build a number such that on the `i`th digit, it's `I_i` based. This number's maxmium value is just `I_1*I_2*...*I_n`. In this way, the entire loop will be collaped into one simple loop

```
for i in range(I_1*I_2*...*I_n):
    # obtain these numbers
    i_1 = f_1(i)
    i_2 = f_2(i)
    ...
    i_n = f_n(i)
    some_function(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)
```

Although the functions to obtain the `i`s are a bit complicated.

Another way to do it is, as you have mentioned, iterators. In Python it's just `import itertools`. In C++, however, I found this [cppitertools](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools/blob/master/README.md). I haven't tried it, but I suppose this could work.

Still, if you want speed, the first approch is preferred. Still, I think there are better solutions.

Comment: tried to come up with a formula but it was too complicated... Still I think this might be the most "flat" solution