# How can I implement a template-driven nested for-loop that is capable of returning a generator?

Tags: c++, for-loop, generator, nested-loops, coroutine

I am attempting to implement a generator that provides subscripts over a multi-dimensional array. Specifically, I am using [the generator implementation by CPP Chrono](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro/blob/master/include/cppcoro/generator.hpp). Since the number of dimensions is driven by the size of an input `shape` array, I needed a recursive function to generate the nested `for` loop. [So far, I have the logic working](https://godbolt.org/z/6nq3qYz3W) for an size-deducted nested for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using Size_t = size_t;
using Int64_t = int;

/// @brief Nested for loop helper
/// @details Recursively generates NLoops nested for loops
template <size_t Index = 0, Size_t NLoops>
void nested_for_loop(const std::array<Size_t, NLoops>& shape, std::array<Int64_t, NLoops>& outSubscripts) {
    if constexpr (Index == NLoops) {
        // Base case: All nested loops have run.
        // Operation is performed here
        for (size_t i = 0; i < NLoops; ++i) {
            std::cout << outSubscripts[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

    } else {
        // Recursive case: Loop from 0 to array[Index]
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= shape[Index]; ++i) {
            outSubscripts[Index] = i; // Store the current subscript
            nested_for_loop<Index + 1>(shape, outSubscripts); // Recursively call for the next loop
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    std::array<Size_t, 3> shape = {2, 30, 6};
    std::array<int, 3> outSubscripts{};

    Int64_t outIndex = 0;
    nested_for_loop(shape, outSubscripts);

    return 0;
}
```

This is capable of printing out the subscripts that I want. If this was just a regular old for-loop, I could just add a `co_yield` to where the operation logic is, update the function return type to `generator<MyDesiredArrayType>`, and call it a day. However, it doesn't seem possible to convert this recursive approach to a generator function.

Is there a better approach to unrolling this `for` loop so that I can properly yield from a coroutine? The only approach that I've been able to come up with is the [one described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53893670). I'd rather not have to resort to something like this, because I don't think there is a `constexpr` approach to converting the linear loop index into the `N` desired subscripts, and I don't want to incur the runtime cost of the extra  additions/multiplications.

There is always the option for me to manually write out a series of `if constexpr` statements. I could add `M` conditional blocks, so I'd be supporting from 0 up to `M` nested for loops. However, this would be so tedious and restrictive that it's silly. There surely must be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your recursive function to that simple iterative function:

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool next_cartesian_product(const std::array<std::size_t, N>& shape,
                            std::array<std::size_t, N>& cur)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        if (++cur[N - 1 - i] > shape[N - 1 - i]) {
            cur[N - 1 - i] = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5zMvThcGM)

Turning it into generator should be trivial now.